# Why the height of my UISegmentedControl is one point bigger than its height constraint?

Tags: ios, swift, uisegmentedcontrol

As you can see on this screenshot, I added a constraint for the height of my `UISegmentedControl` but it is always one point smaller than the height of the `UISegmentedControl`. Any idea why?

[image]

Comment: It seems it's linked to the "Frame Rectangle" selection. There is no problem with "Alignment Rectangle". Then why adding one point when "Frame Rectangle" is selected?

Answer (score 1):

You have change segment View from `Frame Rectangle` to `Alignment Rectangle`

[image]

Frame Rectangle Take original frame. and Alignment Rectangle take layout frame.

Comment: Yes I realised it as I said in comment but it doesn't explain why there is a difference between the two